# SELECT THE NEXT MONTH VISITED CUSTOMERS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Compliments around L&E venue service and have visited the same L&E or ANY OTHER L&E venue in the next 1 month, then they are considered as SERVICE SEEKERS.

Here we have table:

Table

- Customer_Id
- Case_type
- Property_Type
- date

Table

```
Customer_Id     Case_type       Property_Type     date       
------------------------------------------------------------
12541           Compliments     L&E             2019-04-07  
12542           Compliments     L&E             2019-04-08      
12541           Compliments     L&E             2019-05-09
```

OUTPUT

```
Customer_Id     Property_Type        Date    
--------------------------------------------------
 12541            L&E                2019-05-09
```

Here `CUSTOMER(12541)` Compliments about `L&E(2019-04-09)`. IF the same Customer again visited `L&E` after one month `(2019-05-09)` then select that `Customer(12541)`

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: please also ensure that the sample data matches with the expected output and your description.

Comment: please elaborate further on the logic

Comment: use lead and lag function

Comment: If the customer who have Case_type as Compliment and Property_type AS L&E
who's date is  (2019-04-09) in the table , if he has visited in the next  month that is (2019-05-09) then we have to take those customers

Comment: how about `select customer_Id, max(date) from your_table where Case_type = 'Compliment' and Property_type ='L&E'   group by customer_Id` ?

Comment: You are looking for customers that saw the same `property_type` in two adjacent months (e.g. April 2019 and May 2019). In that case you want to show the newer date. But you have still not precisely defined the rules. **(1)** Are we looking only at `case_type = 'Compliment'`? **(2)** Is it about any month? Or just in 2019? Or even only April 2019 and May 2019? **(3)** If looking at several months, which row(s) would you show for visits in April 2019 and May 2019 and June 2019? Which row(s) would you show for visits in April 2019 and May 2019 and September 2019 and October 2019?

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? Do you have an algorithm and don't know how to transform it to SQL? Or do you have a SQL query already that doesn't do what you want. If so what does it do? Show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query will give output when we have ((12541,'L&E','2019-05-07'))this record in visitor table(for one month) else only check  Date > DATEADD(day, 1, Closed_date)   in where clause

```
select t2.Customer_Id, t2.Date from  tbl1 t1 inner join tbl2 t2 on 
t1.Customer_Id=t2.Customer_Id 
where Dated between DATEADD(day, 1, Closed_date) and DATEADD(month, 1, Closed_date)
```